# How to center left floated items for mobile phone view in CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I have a webpage that looks fine on a desktop PC but not as good on a mobile phone as the items on the grid float to the left but I'd like them to appear centered. Is there a simple "@media only screen" code I could add or anything I could change to my below CSS so that it centers on a mobile? Also, the **div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6"** and here is an 
[Image Example: Desktop vs Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uy14.jpg)

You can also check out a live example at - http://www.helpme.ae/

```
.GRID
width:170px;
height:235px;
background:#f4f4f4;
border:1px solid #dedede;
padding:4px;
border-radius:4px;
text-align: center;
float:left;
margin:9px;
margin-bottom:20px;
position:relative

.XOX
display: block;
margin-bottom: 3px;
margin-top: 0px; 
overflow:hidden

.widget-container
{
text-align:left
}

.widget-container ul { padding:0; margin:0; list-style-type:none }
.widget-container ul li { margin-bottom:6px; }
```

Comment: make it by float:none  and text-align:center

Comment: That doesn't work. I've been trying all sorts of variations for many weeks and nothing I do fixes it. Ideally I'd like it to stay as is for the Desktop and just make it center for Mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .latest-posted-tasks-big {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .latest-posted-tasks-big > * {
    text-align: initial;
  }
  .latest-posted-tasks-big > .grid_task {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```